# how to value hh:mm in Ms Excel correctly so that certain values can be assigned to it

Tags: excel, vba

Please could anyone kindly help. Thanking you in advance. My problem is as the following:
I have thousands lines of data with two clusters of time. One is in sheet1, for example, random times from 16pm to 20pm or 4 hours or 240 minutes, I would like to give value to them i.e. 1 to 241

```
(column B)
A       B
17:19   
17:19   
17:19   
18:06   
18:06   
18:06   
16:30   
16:30   
16:30
```

I have a second sheet which will give values to sheet1 column B, the content of sheet2 is:

```
16:00   1
16:01   2
16:02   3
.
.
.
17:19   80
17:20   81
17:21   82
.
.
.
18:06   127
18:07   128
18:08   129
.
.
.
16:30   31
16:31   32
16:32   33
.
.
.
19:58   239
19:59   240
20:00   241
```

I tried to use VLOOKUP, hour, minute to get values for sheet1 B, using sheet2 but I am still unsuccessful (I kept getting false value from comparing two columns containing times) e.g. in sheet1 column B, say B2 I have

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2,'sheet2'!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

My solution did not work. if possible I should get sheet1 filled in like

```
A       B
17:19   80
17:19   80
17:19   80
18:06   127
18:06   127
18:06   127
16:30   31
16:30   31
16:30   31
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an excel formula like this:

```
B2:  =(HOUR(A2)*60)+MINUTE(A2)+1
```

This is just calculating the number of minutes after midnight.  If you wanted to start at say, 16:00, you would just modify it like this:

Set a value somewhere that is the START time...  In this example I have "$E$4" set to 16:00

```
=(HOUR(A3-$E$4)*60)+MINUTE(A3)+1
```

You could put your start time on another sheet or anywhere.

Of course you can always add the If statement to deal with empty rows:

```
=IF(A2="","",(HOUR(A3-$E$4)*60)+MINUTE(A3)+1)
```

In the example, note in the screenshot in column A, the formatting is TIME for row 2, and General for rows 3 & 4.  The formula will work for either.

[image: Basic Formulas]

edit:added IF statement & description of screenshot.
EDIT AFTER COMMENT: Modified formula to add 1 minute.

[image: Modified]

Comment: Sorry, but I tried your solution and it did not work. The time is randomly appearing from 16:00 to 20:00 or 240 minutes which has to be mapped from 1 to 241

Comment: Check the solution now.

Comment: If someone provides you with an answer that is consistently 1 off from what you wanted, over hundreds of records.  Simply add 1 to the equation...  This is the solution you asked for.

Comment: @bennyhardjono, no need to thank in the comments.  On this site, if you feel an answer gave you the information you need to solve the problem, select it an answer so people searching know what worked without having to read all the comments.  I'm glad it helped though.  There are still no answers selected.

Answer (score 0):

I finally, found a correct answer
=(HOUR(A2)-16)*60+MINUTE(A2)+1
so 16:00 will give 1, 16:30 will give 31, 17:19 will give 80 and so on, 20:00 will give 241.
Thanks for trying to help, PJ Rosenburg. Indeed I was on right track in using hour and minute, BUT I do not even need to use VLOOKUP.

Comment: That is what I posted.  In my formula, the value of 16 is set by a cell $E$4.  You can hard code it or set it.  Isn't that what you wanted?